# Конфликт. Как избежать?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день!
При подключении скриптов:

```
// Запускаем отмену прокрутки страницы обложки
function OffScroll() {
  var winScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    $(window).scrollTop(winScrollTop);
  });
}
OffScroll();
// Восстанавливаем прокрутку
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.open').click(function() {
    $(window).unbind('scroll');
  });
});

// Закрываем обложку
$(function() {
    $('.open').click(function(){ $('.cover').fadeToggle(1000); });
});
```

Перестают работать следующие скрипты:

```
// Дублируем название
jQuery(function(f){
    var element = f('#top-panel-h1');
    f(window).scroll(function(){
        element['fade'+ (f(this).scrollTop() > 66 ? 'In': 'Out')](100);
    });
});

// Кнопка вверх
$(function(){
  $.fn.scrollToTop=function(){
    $(this).hide().removeAttr("href");
    if($(window).scrollTop()!="0"){
        $(this).fadeIn("slow")
  }
  var scrollDiv=$(this);
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop()=="0"){
    $(scrollDiv).fadeOut("slow")
    }else{
    $(scrollDiv).fadeIn("slow")
  }
  });
    $(this).click(function(){
      $("html, body").animate({scrollTop:0},"fast")
    })
  }
});
$(function() {$("#top").scrollToTop();});
```

Кнопка вверх и дубль названия при прокрутки страницы не отображаются.  Как избежать конфликта? Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: ну так вы сами scroll отменили.

Comment: попробуйте посмотреть в сторону [event.namespace](https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/) это позволит отписывать конкретные события, кроме того вместо bind/undind лучше сразу on/off так как они и так напрямую вызываются внутри bind/undind

Comment: какие другие скрипты?